# change all the list element to true in pythonic way

Tags: python, list

A list with elements :

```
mylist = [3,7,8,9,2,4,6]
```

just wanted to change all its value to true

```
mylist = [True,True,True,True,True,True,True]
```

i can do it with for loop.

wanted to do in pythonic way preferably one liner

Comment: pythonic != one-liner.

Comment: for loops Are Pythonic..!

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but in your example you are _not_ changing all of the values of a list to `True`. You have created a brand new list, which is the same size as the original list, just with the values set to `True`. The latter is probably what you want, but there is a massive, massive difference between (1) mutating a list by changing the elements it contains and (2) creating a new list with elements derived from those in the original list. It may not seem like a big deal, but it really is. Which of the two things would you like to see? Mutation or new list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just wanted less lines of code, thats why i said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `lambda` with `map` function

```
In [11]: mylist = [3,7,8,9,2,4,6]
#python 2.7
In [12]: mylist = map(lambda x: True,mylist)
#python 3.x
In [12]: mylist = list(map(lambda x: True,mylist))
In [13]: mylist
Out[13]: [True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Comment: Looks like you written the code in `python2`. Bcz `mylist = map(lambda x: True,mylist)` return a map object in python3, so we need to call `list()` explicily get the required output. Also the lamda argument `x` is not used anywhere,  so it would better to write `map(lambda : True,mylist)`

Comment: Cute, but in terms of being Pythonic, it's worth pointing out that the designer of Python does not like `map` and in fact, most Python programming use list comprehensions in place of `map`. The `map` function is cool and all, but few people would consider it "Pythonic." In fact, it's probably un-Pythonic. Perfect for Haskell and JavaScript though. :) Cheers.

Comment: @RayToal i completely agree, but for low size of list i prefer to use map and ofcourse mostly use comprehension

Answer (score 7):

```
mylist = [True for _ in mylist]
```

Comment: Since `item` is not used anywhere it would be better to write `mylist = [True for _ in mylist]`

Comment: @kingkupps list comprehensions are for loops OP said the solution need to pythonic and one liner,not for loop.

Comment: @pylist No prob!

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do this (in this way we're more in Perl-land than Python):

```
# List duplication
mylist = [True] * len(mylist)

# Comprehensions
mylist = [True for x in mylist]

# Fill with itertools
from itertools import repeat
mylist = repeat(True, len(mylist) - 1)
```

All of these *replace* the given list bound to `mylist` with a new list.  If you want to mutate the list that `mylist` points to in-place you can use indexing assignment:

```
# Assignment (mutates existing list)
mylist[:] = [True] * len(mylist)
```

Comment: Which one is Pythonic?

Comment: They all are. The list duplication and list mutation ones are the most Idiomatic, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you :

```
>>> mylist = [True] * len(mylist)
```

Explanation : Initialize list with default value = True and size same as the existing list.